# Get distinct items from a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of objects with three integer properties. How can I get the distinct values of first integer property from my list?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This should work,

```
List<int> result = YourListObject.Select(o => o.FirstInteger).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: +1 List<int> result = YourListObject.Select(o => o.FirstInteger).AsParallel().Distinct().ToList()  "AsParallel()"  might give some performance benfit, if we doesn't care about order and have more items in the list.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

`var g = collection.Select(i => i.Property1).Distinct();`

Could you post some source code so that we can give you a better example?

EDIT:

In my example, I have a collection `collection` which contains numerous instances of your class. I'm then selecting `Property1` from each class, filtering to the distinct values of that property.

Answer (score 8):

I have found this useful and working fine for me for strings.

```
var distinctNames = (from d in YourList select d).Distinct();
```

Hope this is useful for some one like me searching for details in SO.

Answer (score 3):

Example of a more complex distinct'ing....

```
licenseLookupItems = tmpList
                .GroupBy(x => new {x.LicenseNumber, x.Name, x.Location, x.Active, x.Archived})
                .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault())
                .Select(p => new LicenseNumberLookupItem
                {
                    LicenseNumber = p.LicenseNumber,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Location = p.Location,
                    Active = p.Active,
                    Archived = p.Archived
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Nice to pull multiple distinct parts of a record