# Add distinct items from a list to another list

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array, unique

I would like to accomplish what the title states but I don't know how to go about doing so.

I have 2 lists:

```
public List<int[,]> LongList = new List<int[,]>();
public List<int[,]> UniqueList = new List<int[,]>();
```

To further explain, here's a scenario:

Puzzles:

```
public int[,] puzzle1 = new int [3,3] { {1,2,3},
                                            {8,4,0},
                                            {7,6,5} }; //[1,2,3;8,4,0;7,6,5]

    public int[,] puzzle2 = new int [3,3] { {8,7,6},
                                            {1,0,5},
                                            {2,3,4}  }; //[8,7,6;1,0,5;2,3,4]


    public int[,] puzzle3 = new int [3,3] { {7,6,3},
                                            {1,0,2},  
                                            {8,4,5}  }; //[7,6,3;1,0,2;8,4,5]
```

LongList contains:

```
LongList.Add(puzzle1); 
LongList.Add(puzzle1); 
LongList.Add(puzzle1); 
LongList.Add(puzzle1);
LongList.Add(puzzle2);
LongList.Add(puzzle2);
LongList.Add(puzzle3);
LongList.Add(puzzle3);
LongList.Add(puzzle3);
```

I would like Unique list to hold the UNIQUE values from LongList.
AS IF this happened:

```
UniqueList.Add(puzzle1);
UniqueList.Add(puzzle2);
UniqueList.Add(puzzle3);
```

As an equation: UniqueList = Distinct values from LongList

List is full of multiple reoccurring values & I would like to take only the unique ones and put them into `UniqueList`.

I'm trying to complete a puzzle and the `LongList` will contain multiple references of the same same puzzle and more. To make it simple for case of discussion:

`LongList` values: 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5

I would like `UniqueList` to contain the puzzles: 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639036/get-distinct-items-from-a-list

Comment: you can check out this question's answers, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388361/getting-all-unique-items-in-a-c-sharp-list

Comment: @IsmetAlkan it's not nearly duplicate

Comment: Will you have the same objects several times, or different objects with the same content?

Comment: The issue is that there's no inbuilt comparator that is appropriate, or even a good equality operation for multidimensional arrays. Leveraging some of the examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423318/how-to-compare-arrays-in-c perhaps might help.

Comment: @caerolus I don't think it's exact duplicate too, I said possible as you see, but it's absolutely "nearly" duplicate, I think.

Comment: I don't think he needs array comparison here, according to list values he gave now.

Comment: Are you actually using multidimensional arrays? This doesn't make as much sense if you are

Comment: Shouldn't the uniqueList be `List<int>` then?

Comment: Yeah I using multidimensional arrays (I'm 100% sure), they hold the states for the puzzle I'm trying to solve. What do you suggest doesn't make sense?

Comment: Or, if you wanted to flatten each `int[,]` individually, perhaps a `List<int[]>`?

Comment: Let's say you have a two element list with: { [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[2, 2], [4, 5]] }. Do you turn that into { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } or { [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 4, 5] } ?

Comment: Neither I believe (forgive me if I'm wrong). Please check edited question.

Comment: What happens if there's another puzzle (puzzle4) with exactly the same values as puzzle3? Should it be included?

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your patience (also caerolus). That scenario shouldn't arise so I don't believe it will be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's comments are vague.

**Option 1: Unique numbers from across all multidimensional arrays**

```
List<int> UniqueList = new List<int>();

UniqueList = LongList.Select(i => Flatten(i))
               .SelectMany(i => i)
               .Distinct()
               .ToList();
```

This would turn { [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[2, 2], [4, 5]] } to { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

See below for `Flatten`

**Option 2: Unique multidimensional arrays by values**

NB: Assumes size and number of dimensions of each multidimensional array match.

```
List<int[,]> UniqueList = new List<int[,]>();
foreach (var e in LongList)
{
  IEnumerable<int> flat = Flatten(e);
  if (!UniqueList.Any(i => Flatten(i).SequenceEqual(flat)))
  {
    UniqueList.Add(e);
  }
}
```

This would turn { [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[2, 2], [4, 5]] } to { [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[2, 2], [4, 5]] }

See below for `Flatten`

**Option 3: Unique references only**

```
UniqueList = aList.Distinct().ToList();
```

NB: This was the original answer, for context on the comments.

**Flatten Method**

In all cases `Flatten` is taken from [Guffa's SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423376/364)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(T[,] items) {
  for (int i = 0; i < items.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < items.GetLength(1); j++)
      yield return items[i, j];
}
```

**Other options**

If OP would like something else (e.g. flattenting `List<int[,]>` to `List<int[]>` or support for different sized multidimensional arrays) they will have to comment back.

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'unique'. I ran a test in LINQPad and it matched my intuition. I'll grab the code and post back.

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't.

Comment: By unique I mean:

List would contain values: 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5 (made simple for explanation as they're actually multi dimensional results).

And I only want UniqueList to hold: 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Yeah it performs reference equality, not same value equality. Okay deleting my answer as it's incorrect for what the OP wants.

Comment: I don't think your explanation is simplifying. It actually complicates it. Can you give a multi-D example of what you're after? It sounds like only the unique numbers across all multi-dimensional arrays? Or a set of multi-dimensional arrays that only contain the unique numbers in each corresponding source array?

Comment: Im sorry, please have a look at my edited question. If you need more info please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Based on OP's update, we just need to remove duplicate **references**. So we do not need to compare on a per-value basis. `Distinct` should do:

```
UniqueList = LongList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: haha my first answer... I'm upvoting you anyway for being as patient with this as I was :-)

Comment: I was just thinking about it...update yours and let that be the answer :-) btw...I'm not sure if it's really just references or he just made that example to keep it simple...

Comment: Based on his comment that it "contains multiple references of the same puzzle" you sound like you've interpreted it right to me.

Comment: not sure, really. +1 to you too and let him decide what he means :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!
If I were to call upon the unique list like so:

UniqueList[0]
UniqueList[1]
UniqueList[2]

I would need that to grab puzzle1, puzzle2 & puzzle 3 (with NO duplicates that the LongList holds).. Does this code provide that?