# String[] receive distinct from a List

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list being created with data from a DataBase.
The structure from the list is:

```
    public struct GetInfoForGraph
    {
        public float A { get; set; }
        public float B { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public String Customer_name { get; set; }
        public String Type_name { get; set; }
        public String Program_name { get; set; }
        public int Id_Tbl_Program { get; set; }
        public int Id_Tbl_File_Names { get; set; }
        public string File_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I add data in the list like this:

```
public List<GetInfoForGraph> CreatesListInfoForGraphPoints()
{
    string sqlCommand = "SELECT A AS A";
    sqlCommand += ", B AS B";
    sqlCommand += ", TIME_FORMATTED AS Time";
    sqlCommand += ", CUSTOMER_NAME As Customer_name";
    sqlCommand += ", PROGRAM_NAME As Program_name";
    sqlCommand += ", TYPE_NAME As Type_name";
    sqlCommand += ", ID_TBL_PROGRAM AS Id_Tbl_Program";
    sqlCommand += ", ID_TBL_FILE_NAMES as Id_Tbl_File_Names";
    sqlCommand += ", ONLY_FILE_NAME as File_Name";
    sqlCommand += "  FROM VW_MAIN_INFO";
    sqlCommand += "  where CUSTOMER_NAME = '" + Project.CustomerName + "'";
    sqlCommand += "  and PROGRAM_NAME = '" + Project.ProgramName + "'";
    sqlCommand += "  and TYPE_NAME = '" + Project.TypeName + "'";
    sqlCommand += "  ORDER BY Time";

    List<GetInfoForGraph> DataForGraph = new List<GetInfoForGraph>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"XXXX");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DataForGraph.Add(new GetInfoForGraph()
            {
                A = dr.GetFloat(dr.GetOrdinal("A")),
                B = dr.GetFloat(dr.GetOrdinal("B")),
                Time = dr.GetDateTime(dr.GetOrdinal("Time")),
                Customer_name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Customer_name")),
                Program_name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Program_name")),
                Type_name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Type_name")),
                Id_Tbl_Program = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id_Tbl_Program")),
                Id_Tbl_File_Names = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id_Tbl_File_Names")),
                File_Name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("File_Name"))
            });

        }
        dr.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ActivityLog.LogError(new StackTrace(true), ex);
    }
    finally
    {

        conn.Close();
    }

    return DataForGraph;

} // End of List<GetInfoForGraph> CreatesListInfoForGraphPoints()
```

I would like to add on my "DropDown" event the following information:

- Distinct from the File_name from the list

What I tried:
* Idea from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639036/get-distinct-items-from-a-list)

```
        private void CboxReceiveNameFile_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<int> result = DataForGraph.Select(o => o.FirstInteger).Distinct().ToList();

    }
```

But it is giving me the error 'object' does not containt a definition for Select and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'object'...

Does any body can help me? Any help is welcome! Thank you

Comment: First thing to do before anything else: stop generating SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead.This leads to clearer code, avoids problematic conversions, and avoids SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance - it would clarify the fact you are defining `object DataForGraph` and also avoid embarrassment by hiding the SQL injection sample...

Comment: Are you importing Linq ? otherwise add using System.Ling to the top of the source file

Comment: In your example, `DataForGraph` is not in scope where you're using it, so it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you for the advice. Who is coding with me, mentioned that in the past, there was a string limit for C# codes, reason why he does this way. Anyway, I will clean this - thank you.

Comment: @JonB, what do you mean it is not in the scope? I mean, I showed where I am creating this list, the structure, and how I am adding information to it.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the string concatenation of the SQL in general. I'm talking about the `"  where CUSTOMER_NAME = '" + Project.CustomerName + "'";` parts. (Admittedly the string concatenation itself would be better either as a verbatim string literal or as a single expression with lots of concatenated operands, but at least that isn't a security concern.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, in this case, what should I do to avoid the problem?

Comment: As I said before, use parameterized SQL.

Comment: @FabioSoares you declare `DataForGraph` in your `CreatesListInfoForGraphPoints` method, and then try to use it in your `CboxReceiveNameFile_DropDown` method. Your variable is in the scope of the method where it is created, so it may only be used within that method. I suspect you have another variable declared elsewhere with the same name, and that is the source of your problem.